# How do I upload file to google drive?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have checked out tons of links for upload file directly in Google Drive.
I have created a sample application and it's working as expected, but the problem is it's requires the user to login with Google account.

I want to make an web application, where the user who's selecting file can directly upload it to **example@gmail.com** Google drive. So user don't have to signing with own google account.

How can I achieve a goal?

It's a great help if you have a sample code for this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads

Comment: This would be a security violation. I don't want you or your users typing my email address in and uploading onto my Google Drive without my permission.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Google Drive needs an account to authenticate and know where to upload the file.

If you want to upload it to a shared place, then create an account for that purpose and use those credentials to log in.

But for your case, if it's not a requirement to use google drive but just a cloud file storage, SmartFile is a lot better for that kind of programs, I'm using it in my own projects and works like a charm, check the Developer account, it gives you 100Gb of space and 200Gb of monthly traffic, and uses a very clean REST api (I have no relatinoship with them, just a happy user).

https://www.smartfile.com/